# How to integrate Facebook Share button without code?

Tags: facebook, social-sharing, social-connect

We are using this code for Facebook share button. We placed this code in our functions.php But we are getting pagenot found in fb share popup window. How to fix this issue.

```
<span class="fb-share-button" data-href="<?php wp_get_shortlink(); ?>" data-layout="button_count"></span>
```